# Problems in conditional validation with Yup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yup

*In two fields with validation, one of them, needs to be requested if the other has not filled in and vice versa
Doing it that way*

```
       email: yup.string().email().when('phone', {
        is: (phone) => !phone || phone.length === 0,
        then: yup.string().email().required(),
        otherwise: yup.string()
    }),
    phone: yup.string().when('email', {
        is: (email) => !email || email.length === 0,
        then: yup.string().required(),
        otherwise: yup.string()
    })
});
```

**In my way I have the following error: "Error: Cyclic dependency, node was: value"**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you can do is to create a *Shape*

```js
const obj = yup.object().shape({
  email: yup.string().email()
    .when('phone', {
      is: (phone) => !phone || phone.length === 0,
      then: yup.string().email().required(),
      otherwise: yup.string()
    })
  phone: yup.string()
    .when('email', {
      is: (email) => !email || email.length === 0,
      then: yup.string().required(),
      otherwise: yup.string()
    })
}, ['email', 'phone'])
```

Comment: It worked for me, too, thank you! Can you please explain what the array at the end does? That was I needed to add, but I don't see what is gained by this.

Comment: How we can do this in typescript ? Because when I add the array at the bottom, it will work but it still complains Type 'string' is not assignable to type '[string, string]'.ts(2322)

Comment: For anyone else struggling with this in TypeScript, I found that using `[['email', 'phone']]` rather than `['email', 'phone']` (so wrap the values in square braces) fixed this issue. This may have been because I was dealing with Yup array though

Answer (score 1):

```
const obj = yup.object().shape({
  email: yup.string().email().required()
          .when('phone', (phone, schema) => (phone[0] !== undefined ? schema.notRequired() : schema)),

  phone: yup.string().required()
    .when('phone', (email, schema) => (email[0] !== undefined ? schema.email().notRequired() : schema))
}, ['email', 'phone'])
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).